# How to link two videos in a website to play at the same time on hover with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

So I am helping my gf with her Uni project. She is a graphic designer and she needed some help with creating a webpage with a video comics.
I made it so that the videos would play on hover with Javascript (this is the first time ever I had to use JS) and now I need a way to bind some of them together - e.g. you hover on one or the other and both play, you remove the mouse and both stop. And I need to do it several times. The website will contain a total of 24 Videos.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.video').each(function() {
          $(this).on("mouseover", function(e) { hoverVideo(e); });
          $(this).on("mouseout", function(e) { hideVideo(e); });
        });
      });
      function hoverVideo(i) {
          i.target.play();
      }
      function hideVideo(i) {
          i.target.pause();
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>
      *Hover over each frame to see the story.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="firstrow">
      <div class="video" id="one" >
        <video class="thevideo" loop>
          <source src="Resources/1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="video" id="one" >
        <video class="thevideo" loop>
          <source src="Resources/2.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="video" id="one" >
        <img src="Resources/text/tap.svg"  />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you be more precise with the question? You want all of the videos play if mouse is hovering any of them?

Comment: _you hover on one or the other and both play, you remove the mouse and both stop_ , play only the one video where the mouse is hovering on correct ? How can you play more than one when you want them to stop when the mouse moves out ?

Comment: Currently the only video that plays is the one on which the mouse is hovering. I need a way to make both videos in the sample code to play together at the same time when the mouse is hovering on either and to stop when the mouse isn't hovering.

Comment: Basically I'm separating them in to sort of scenes and I don't know how to do it so when you are hovering inside of the div which contains all the video sources for that scene, all of them to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with mouse enter and leave events to avoid redudancy of triggering the execution everytime your mouse is inside the video with movements

```js
$(".thevideo").mouseenter(function(){
  console.log("mouse is entered");
  $(".thevideo").each(function(){
    this.play();
  })
})
$(".thevideo").mouseleave(function(){
  $(".thevideo").each(function(){
    this.pause()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.video').each(function() {
          $(this).on("mouseover", function(e) { hoverVideo(e); });
          $(this).on("mouseout", function(e) { hideVideo(e); });
        });
      });
      function hoverVideo(i) {
          i.target.play();
      }
      function hideVideo(i) {
          i.target.pause();
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>
      *Hover over each frame to see the story.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="firstrow">
      <div class="video" id="one" >
        <video class="thevideo" loop>
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="video" id="one" >
        <video class="thevideo" loop>
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="video" id="one" >
        <img src="Resources/text/tap.svg"  />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are only calling the function on 1 video - the video that triggered the event `i.target.play();`

So you just need to toggle `pause` and `play` on all videos inside `.firstrow` instead:

```
$(".firstrow .video").on("mouseenter", ()=>{
  $(".firstrow video").each((index, video)=>{
    video.play();
  });
});

$(".firstrow .video").on("mouseleave", ()=>{
  $(".firstrow video").each((index, video)=>{
    video.pause();
  });
});
```

Comment: Things is, there are only two videos for now, but after tomorrow there will be 22 more. And I need, for example, only these two to play together, the rest to play only on hover.

Comment: @Dark_Witcher Please see edit - you just have to tweak the 2 selectors until they match what you need. This will now play the 2 videos within `.firstrow` only.